# How to retrieve specific text from the given string in the c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to retrieve specific text from the following string.I have some bold tags and paragraph tags in the string.I want to retrieve only text which in under bold tag( **...** ).This is my requirement.I want to store the retrieved values in the string array.

```
SampleText<b>Billgates</b><p>This is Para</p><b>SteveJobs</b>ThisisEnd
```

Need to achieve this in the c#.Output as follows.

```
str[0] = Billgates
str[1] = SteveJobs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] strArray = new string[50];
            string str = "SampleText<b>Billgates</b><p>This is Para</p><b>SteveJobs</b>ThisisEnd";

            Regex expression = new Regex(@"\<b\>(.*?)\</b\>");

            for (int i = 0; i < expression.Matches(str).Count; ++i)
            {
                string value = expression.Matches(str)[i].ToString();

                value = value.Replace("<b>", "");
                value = value.Replace("</b>", "");
                strArray[i] = value;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(strArray[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(strArray[1]);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try parsing it via Regex:

```
Regex expression = new Regex(@"\<b\>(.*?)\<b\>"); //This matches anything between <b> and </b>

foreach (Match match in expression.Matches(code)) //Code being the string that contains '...<b>BillGates</b>...<b>etc</b>...'
{
    string value = match.Groups[1].Value;
    //And from here do whatever you like with 'value'
}
```

Comment: You mean match.Groups[1].Value, I think.

Comment: **Edit:** Whoops, it seems I misconstrued you, you are correct yes!